# Copy Data from multiple table to one table without duplicate

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to insert data from `Source` (1&2) tables to `Destination` table without duplicates

Table: `Source`

```
       SONGs       ARTISTs         ALBUM s
       Baby         John          RocknRoll
       Moon         Mike          Moonlight
       Firefly      Chad           Garden
```

Table: `Source2`

```
       SONGs       ARTISTs         ALBUMs
       Happy        Jane           Fresh
       Baby         John          RocknRoll
       Bday         Zelda           Link
```

Table: `Destination`

```
ID     SONG       ARTIST         ALBUM       CATALOG#     TRACK#   <--- Columns
 1     baby        John        RocknRoll
```

Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO Destination
     (SONG,
     ARTIST,
     ALBUM)

SELECT DISTINCT
     So.SONGs,
     So.ARTISTs,
     So.ALBUMs,
     FROM Source So

LEFT JOIN Destination Ds
     ON Ds.SONG= So.SONGs
     AND Ds.ARTIST= So.ARTISTs
     AND Ds.ALBUM= So.ALBUMs

WHERE
     Ds.SONG IS NULL
 AND Ds.SONG IS NULL
 AND Ds.SONGIS NULL
```

However after trying this code on both table i still get a duplicate

I Tried UNION but I have more than 2 source table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `UNION` istead of `JOIN`

```
INSERT INTO Destination
     (SONG,
     ARTIST,
     ALBUM)

SELECT 
     So.SONGs,
     So.ARTISTs,
     So.ALBUMs
FROM (
     SELECT So.SONGs,
            So.ARTISTs,
            So.ALBUMs
     FROM Source

     UNION

     SELECT So.SONGs,
            So.ARTISTs,
            So.ALBUMs
     FROM Source2

     UNION

     SELECT So.SONGs,
            So.ARTISTs,
            So.ALBUMs
     FROM Source3

     UNION

     SELECT So.SONGs,
            So.ARTISTs,
            So.ALBUMs
     FROM Source4

     UNION

     SELECT So.SONGs,
            So.ARTISTs,
            So.ALBUMs
     FROM Source5

     )
WHERE
     Ds.SONG IS NULL
 AND Ds.SONG IS NULL
 AND Ds.SONGIS NULL
```

Comment: How can i make this possible if I have more than 2 `source` table? and what code should I use when I needed to add data from new `source` table later?

Comment: Thank you. it worked for me. But what if I will add data from a new `source` table?. I mean AFTER using your code above

Comment: So you can use  `NOT EXISTS` in your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2):

```
  select SONGs , ARTISTS , ALBUMS
  from Source 

   Union

   select SONGs , ARTISTS , ALBUMS
   from Source2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION` to remove duplicates and add an additional `NOT EXISTS` clause:

```
INSERT INTO Destination(SONG, ARTIST, ALBUM)
    SELECT * 
    FROM(
        SELECT SONGs, ARTISTs, ALBUMs
        FROM Source
        UNION 
        SELECT SONGs, ARTISTs, ALBUMs
        FROM Source2
    )t
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM DESTINATION
            WHERE
                SONG = t.SONGs
                AND ARTIST = t.ARTISTs
                AND ALBUM = t.ALBUMs
        )
```